# Unable to cast object of type in below Linq method

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting following error in below code line No (`var columnNames =` ).

```
`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'.'`
```

Code

```
 public JsonResult SaveData(List<object> customers)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
            var columnNames = ((Dictionary<string, object>)customers[0]).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(columnNames[i]);
            }
            foreach (Dictionary<string, object> customer in customers)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count(); i++)
                {
                    dr[columnNames[i]] = customer[columnNames[i]];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

    

            return Json('1');

        }
```

In javscript console shows passing data

```
0 : {Id: "1", Name: "abc", Country: "uk", __rowNum__: 1}
1: {Id: "2", Name: "kala", Country: "us", __rowNum__: 2}
2: {Id: "3", Name: "Has", Country: "IN", __rowNum__: 3}
```

Comment: Why is the customer `List<object>`?

Comment: I have an excel file and uploading to above controller. In my controller I am expecting all the columns and rows. Using javscript I am getting all data from Excel . I checked all data available before call. But when I am doing the call I am not getting the data

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fill a `Customer` class with appropriate properties and then send in a `List<Customer>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the Reflection.

```cs
var columnNames = customers[0]
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();

foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count(); i++)
    {
        PropertyInfo prop = customer.GetType().GetProperty(columnNames[i]);
        dr[columnNames[i]] = prop.GetValue(customer);
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sFtU8J)

Comment: I also Have 'foreach (Dictionary<string, object>' in below this line in the code. It is also getting error

Comment: Hi, done update my answer, you can't do casting, but need the reflection to do the work.

Comment: for some reason, in my code columnNames  is 0. I am passing data from javascript  to C#

Comment: Can you share the sample data for `customers` to the question?

Comment: in my javacsript console it shows --- I have updated o/p

Comment: Looks fine with your test data. [Sample Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w7Hfzr). Do you check in the controller that you are able to capture the `customers` data?

Comment: In controller I use List<object> customers. Is this problem ? you can see in the parameter of SaveData() method. When I debug it shows count 3 and when I drill down it shows just object. it repeates inside the list for 0,1,2